# Check if gradle tests pass in shell script

Tags: android, bash, testing, gradle

In my android project I want to run tests using shell script. Depending on whether or not tests pass I want to do some further actions. My question is how my script is supposed to know if tests passed? To run tests I use `./gradlew test` command.
It would be nice if the return value of this command would be an integer or boolean but it’s not. This is my `run_tests.sh` at the moment, however it doesn't work because OUTPUT is not a boolean value;

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=$(./gradlew test)

if [ "$OUTPUT" = true ]; then
    echo "Tests passed. Do something."
else
    echo "Tests didn't pass. Do something."
fi
```

This script always prints "Tests didn't pass. Do something.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just checking the exit status of ./gradlew ? 
If the script passes, the exit status will be 0, otherwise it will be 1 or any other return code, usually decided by the script developer.
Also, use double brackets when using bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
./gradlew test

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Tests passed. Do something."
else
    echo "Tests didn't pass. Do something."
fi
```

Comment: this is equal to 0 even if build fails

Comment: it should return non-zero if a failure occurs. In case yours doesn't, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691225/gradle-returns-exit-code-as-0-though-one-of-its-tasks-failed

Comment: yea got it. i was doing a small mistake. this gives non-zero

Answer (score 0):

A bit more correct version of the accepted answer which conforms to the [SC2181](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2181) rule:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! ./gradlew test;
then
    echo "Tests passed. Do something."
else
    echo "Tests didn't pass. Do something."
fi
```

Comment: :) more correct ? So tests will never ever pass again ?

Comment: Whoops, fixed! Thanks